# Base case for an induction proof relating to cycle graphs

Tags: graph-theory

What should the base case be for an induction proof on a general property for Cn, cycle graphs?

Would it be n=2 or n=3? Since n=2 is not a simple graph, I'm guessing it would be the cycle graph on n=3 vertices?

Comment: Yes, there's no cycle graph on 2 vertices, so you'd better start with a triangle.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the proof to be meaningful, as you suggest, you'd need a base case $n = 3$ vertices, as the minimum number of vertices required for a graph to be a cycle is $3$